# How to integrate this script with this function in Python(Instagram)

Tags: python, instagram

I am doing a little script where I want to collect all the "code:" regarding a tag.

For example:

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/%s/?__a=1
```

The next next page will be:

> https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1&max_id=**end_cursor**

However, my drawback is to make each url get me what I need (which are the comments and username of the people).
So as the script works, it does not do what I need.

The "obtain_max_id" function works, getting the following end_cursors, but I do not know how to adapt it.
I appreciate your help!

In conclusion, I need to adapt the "obtain_max_id" function in my "connect_main" function to extract the information I need with each of the URLs.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it that you are looking for exactly?

Comment: How to do the whole process but with each URL, when you finish extracting the data,do the same with the following URL (https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1&max_id=end_cursor)...The steps would be like:
URL - Extract data 
Next url...
URL - Extract data 
....Successively
@Quirk

Comment: I updated my question, please check it out. @Quirk

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.

```
import requests
import json

host = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1"

r = requests.get(host).json()

for x in r['tag']['media']['nodes']:
   print (x['code'])

next = r['tag']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor']

while next:
   r = requests.get(host + "&max_id=" + next ).json()
   for x in r['tag']['media']['nodes']:
      print (x['code'])

   next = r['tag']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
```

Comment: Your max_id is when r['tag']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor'] is None

Answer (score 0):

You have all the data you want in your `data` variable (in JSON form), right after you execute the line:

```
data = json.loads(finish.text)
```

in the `while` loop inside your `obtain_max_id()` method. Just use that.

Assuming everything inside the `else` block of your `connect_main()` method works, you could simple use that code inside the above `while` loop, right after you have all the data in your `data` variable.

Comment: But the question is that the "obtain_max_id" function pulls out the cursors one after the other, and I need to do it one by one for what I said, of the data that I need to extract with JSON for each of the URLs @Quirk

Comment: You are *already* doing that, when you append a value to the `end_cursor[]` and in the next iteration use *that* value to fetch a new page and load it into `data`. When you start with an empty `end_cursor[]` list and add a cursor at every page you visit, you will have visited all the pages corresponding to the cursors, when your loop ends.

Comment: I understand, but when extracting the comments and the user names should be done with another While (while count <40 :) and will remain in an infinite loop, so it will not continue with the other end_cursors and will stay in the First.
My idea was to try to do that every time I ran an end_cursor, it stays statitc, I extract the data and then I make a request to the last end_cursor that was left, so I go running not with a cycle, but in order to advance the script. @Quirk

Comment: And why exactly does it go off into an infinite loop?

Comment: I do not know what else I can do to get the end_cursors. I think that with getting the next end_cursor, that would be enough to put it in a list and that always that list is modified by the following end_cursor, but I do not know how to do it. @Quirk